# Plotting CDF in histogram form in R

Tags: r, histogram, cdf

I am not an expert on stats, but I've been trying to plot a cdf out of an array of points. I've tried R and Python both. These are my example set of points:(1.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,5.5,6)

Using the ecdf function in R, I manage to get this:

[image]

This was my code:

```
data <- c(1.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,5.5,6)
plot(ecdf(data))
```

Is there a way to get the same plotted as a histogram or would that be fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[image]Is this what you mean?

```
par(mar = c(5,5,2,5))
data <- c(1.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,5.5,6)
h <- hist(
  data,
  breaks = seq(0, 10, 1),
  xlim = c(0,10))

par(new = T)

ec <- ecdf(data)
plot(x = h$mids, y=ec(h$mids)*max(h$counts), col = rgb(0,0,0,alpha=0), axes=F, xlab=NA, ylab=NA)
lines(x = h$mids, y=ec(h$mids)*max(h$counts), col ='red')
axis(4, at=seq(from = 0, to = max(h$counts), length.out = 11), labels=seq(0, 1, 0.1), col = 'red', col.axis = 'red')
mtext(side = 4, line = 3, 'Cumulative Density', col = 'red')
```